# can anyone advice with getting count for amount of products in category for specified results with linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have created a set of search results, and I wish to create a filter of available cats, with the number of results within that filter.   however I get the most strangest error when trying to do this.

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'NAMESPACE.Models.Products'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

this is the code i have tried:

```
var cats = (from p in ctx1.SubCategories
                        where myCats.Contains(p.subCategoryId) && p.enabled
                        select new
                            AvailableSubCats
                                   {
                                       CategoryName = p.subCategoryName,
                                       Id = p.subCategoryId,
                                       TotalItems = model.Count(x => x.subCategoryId == p.subCategoryId)
                                   }).Distinct();
```

Products is the object that is called model  on the line of totalItems.
I have also tried this:

```
var cats = from c in ctx1.SubCategories
                       join p in model on c.subCategoryId equals p.subCategorySubId
                       group p by c.subCategoryName
                       into g
                       select new
                           AvailableSubCats
                                  {
                                      CategoryName = g.Key,
                                      Id = 0,
                                      TotalItems = g.Count()
                                  };
```

with the same error, and dont like this because i dont know how to get the name of the category and its ID.

help much appreciated.

thanks

p.s  I am using Entity framework 4.1, .net 4 and MVC 3, mysql

in short i am trying to run this in linq, but were the the products side is already a result

```
select c.*, (select count(productId) from Products where Products.subCategoryId = c.subCategoryId) as counter  from SubCategories c
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try turning your list of products into a list of subCategoryId's so EF can understand it. Something like:

```
var subCategoryIds = model.Select(m => m.subCategoryId);

var cats = (from p in ctx1.SubCategories
ctx1.SubCategories
where myCats.Contains(p.subCategoryId) && p.enabled
select new
    AvailableSubCats
    {
        CategoryName = p.subCategoryName,
        Id = p.subCategoryId,
        TotalItems = subCategoryIds.Count(x => x == p.subCategoryId)
    }).Distinct();
```

Comment: i cant do that, i more or less have that value and is what i have called myCats, but i cant run that as it produces an error of {"Too high level of nesting for select"}, needs to be simpler if thats possible

Comment: yes mysql server, seems to be a mysql only bug, i know its dirty but have looped through the cats, and then put into a temp list and then returned the temp list as   asQueryable  seems to be the only way :-|